# How can I reliably check which is the last time an Ubuntu machine has been connected to the internet?

Tags: networking, internet

How can I reliably check which is the last time an Ubuntu machine has been connected to the internet?

<del>In case this is not possible, a way to check the last time an Ubuntu machine has been connected to a network would be good enough.</del>

Answer (score 28):

**Method 1**

Even though NetworkManager.conf allows logging, that apparently still goes into syslog. However, kern.log also has it.

```
grep 'associated' /var/log/kern.log | tail -n1                               
Jun 21 17:08:25 anaconda kernel: [ 4910.819781] wlan1: associated
```

**Method 2**

I've found that NetworkManager does store last connection time, and it is sorted in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps` file, in the unix epoch time format (seconds since 1970). Mine looks like this for instance:

```
$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps                                       
[timestamps]
c562ac2d-8911-4273-b165-ed1495b28c9a=1432777079
46cfcdd9-d095-418f-acd6-0a7ca282bb9a=0
d81fb3d0-1717-42c0-903d-4622c2381597=1434895707
b0bdefe6-df88-49bb-83d8-154dd21d77d9=1433093286
```

To show the latest entry

```
date --date=@"$( awk -F'=' 'BEGIN {var=0}{if(var<$2) var=$2;} END{print var}' /var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps )"
```

Awk will search for largest epoch time (in other words latest), and date will convert it to human readable form.

I suspect also that this file (`/var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps`) is used by Edit Connections graphical menu to display last time of connection

[image]

The problem is that if you're still connected to an access point, the GUI way keeps showing `now` not, the time when connection was established last

Comment: Where do I find the file? :) Also does this checks the last time the machine has been connected to the internet or the last time the machine has been connected to a network? Lastly, does this work afterwards?

Comment: @kos apparently that still goes into the syslog. I'm gonna research a little more, and if I find something, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok I checked `man NetworkManager.conf`, the file is `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`; this is going to work only after having enabled logging in the daemon, but unfortunately I need to check this afterwards supposing that the machine has not been configured for this. Anyway +1 for the `kern.log` solution and for the first solution which might be helpful in other cases

Comment: @kos I think I found something else. /var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps . It's in epoch time for each AP

Comment: Hmmm `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps` only prints some hexadecimal `-` separated strings (which I have no idea of what they're about). What's the idea exactly?

Comment: I get a bunch of lines like this: `eb0b7ef5-167c-4414-bd49-bd2bda97ad48=1434896310`. The  right hand side is in unix epoch time (i.e. seconds since New Year, 1970)

Comment: @kos  So that file contains hex-string=epoch-timestamp. hex strings are access points. epoch-timestamps are latest time of connection. Try my awk version there, I've edited my answer

Comment: @sebastian_k  can you post the contents of your file to paste.ubuntu.com and link it here ? I cannot believe this to be so different. I'm on 14.04, are you on 15.04 ?

Comment: Ok I see now it's working, nice

Comment: I don't mean to be that guy, but isn't the epoch since 1970?

Comment: @DeadChex I was off by one year :) Corrected already

Comment: @sebastian_k yes, exactly right. So that's what we need - extract largest (latest ) epoch time and convert to human readable form, and we know the latest established connection.  That's my last code `date --date=@$( awk . . .` does

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm not OP, I just wanted to explain the structure of the file and we replied simultaneously :)

Comment: @sebastian_k I know :) While I was editing the answer and reading comments, I was a bit concerned that the file on other versions of ubuntu might be different, so when kos said he only sees hex strings and didn't notice the epoch time after the = sign, I panicked . Anyway, I'm glad everything cleared out now

Comment: Notice that the `associated` messages in the log are only for wireless networks. For wired networks you should look for something else instead (for example the messages about link coming up or down).

Answer (score 6):

You can check the file `/var/log/syslog` it will display the last time you connected to a network.

---

*Example*

```
Jun 21 08:00:00 Ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.0.0.0 on wlan0 to 192.0.0.0 port 67 (xid=0xec7c6e7)
```

You can run a [grep](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/grep) command to pull only what you need from the log

```
< /var/log/syslog grep DHCPREQUEST
```

Comment: +1, still hoping for a way to check the last time it has been connected to the internet. If nothing comes up within today I'll accept this answer. However I'd like to suggest you a little more user-friendly solution such as `< /var/apt/syslog grep DHCPREQUEST` or variations.

Comment: `DHCPREQUEST` is not reliable. I'am online since afternoon and since I had a lot of DHCP requests.

Comment: @Kos you seem to have mistakenly put apt in place of log in your comment.

Comment: @Sri Indeed, that was a slip. Luckily OP didn't fall for that!

Answer (score 5):

Check `CONNECTED_GLOBAL` after we have found `link connected` in `/var/log/syslog`

`/link connected/,/CONNECTED_GLOBAL/`

```
% awk '/link connected/,/CONNECTED_GLOBAL/ {line=$0} END{print line}' /var/log/syslog
Jun 21 11:12:54 sturm NetworkManager[736]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL Jun 21 11:12:54

% awk '/link connected/,/CONNECTED_GLOBAL/ {month=$1;day=$2;time=$3} END{print month,day,time}' /var/log/syslog
Jun 21 11:12:54
```

Comment: There's no need for `sudo` in the first one, however none of these is working, I think it's because of the POSIXly `[[:space:]]`. Which version of `awk` are you running?

Comment: @kos Ups, `sudo` removed. GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p11, GNU MP 6.0.0)

Comment: Ok now it's working :). +1

Comment: @kos I need my `%` ;) If there is a output in the line below

Comment: I don't like `%`. All but this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find the "right" way to do this, you can always manufacture your own!

The following bash function will tell you if you're online (to the Internet) or not.

You would just have to write a script which calls it (in a loop and then sleeps) and records the last date and time to a file (overwriting, so it just has just the latest value).

You would have to add code to the loop so it checks as soon as it is initially called and logs (so your initial state is set correctly).

After that, you would only log again when the state first goes offline and when it first comes online after being offline. It's easier to code than to explain. ;)

This would be limited in accuracy by how long a delay (sleep) you use in the loop (to keep it from being a very tight loop that might consume too many system resources.) It would also be unaware of whatever happens before it is started or when it is not running.

The script itself could be started (as a background job (`&` at the end of the invocation), possibly with a `nohup` to keep it running if its parent process terminates) when your user logs in by running it from your $HOME/.profile file, starting it with your desktop autostart utility (KDE or Gnome), from a cron job that periodically checks to see if it's not already running, or even from whatever startup system you have (init/systemd/etc., if you know enough to do that.)

When you can't find something like this that does exactly what you want, it's often not too hard to write your own script to do it and run it like a daemon in the background.

It is best to run it from a regular user account if possible - unless you code it in a robust language like C or Python - because shell scripts running with root privileges often pose security risks.

This approach has another issue. Sometimes a ping will timeout giving you a false offline status.

I have a full script, [offline_alert](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/offline_alert), which pretty much does the opposite of what you want - alerts me when I go offline - but the code may prove useful. It has a better offline function which attempts to reduce false positives from ping timeouts.

```
function offline {
  ## Test if offline
  ## Returns 0 if online, 2 if offline
  local RC
  ping -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1
  RC=$?
  ##echo "offline returning [${RC}]"
  return $RC
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to check any service/daemon log that relay on Internet to work. For example NTP (Network Time Protocol) updates.

See `dpkg -L ntpdate` for network state hooks

Well as I have checked its log for Ubuntu desktop , its update run whenever network up and keep trying after short delay if last update failed. It  connects `ntp.ubuntu.com`.

(Note, I added first column in the output for my comments)

```
$ grep -r ntpdate /var/log/syslog*

1st_trial   Jul 14 00:35:56 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[774]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 14 00:35:56 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[774]: no servers can be used, exiting
2nd_trial   Jul 14 03:38:57 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2571]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 14 03:38:57 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2571]: no servers can be used, exiting
3rd_trial   Jul 14 03:46:09 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2782]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 14 03:46:09 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2782]: no servers can be used, exiting
4th_trial   Jul 14 03:47:48 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2917]: step time server 91.189.89.199 offset 3.458355 sec
1st_trial   Jul 14 10:23:07 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[728]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 14 10:23:07 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[728]: no servers can be used, exiting
2nd_trial   Jul 14 10:37:22 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2099]: step time server 91.189.89.199 offset 2.021103 sec
dis-/re-con Jul 14 15:27:09 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[20174]: step time server 91.189.89.199 offset 1.677465 sec
1st_trial   Jul 14 23:55:00 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[807]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 14 23:55:00 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[807]: no servers can be used, exiting
2nd_trial   Jul 15 00:00:24 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2041]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset 1.619839 sec
1st_trial   Jul 15 05:39:08 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[767]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 15 05:39:08 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[767]: no servers can be used, exiting
2nd_trial   Jul 15 05:39:21 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[1088]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset 2.897077 sec
1st_trial   Jul 15 05:49:40 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[787]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
            Jul 15 05:49:40 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[787]: no servers can be used, exiting
2nd_trial   Jul 15 05:49:50 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[1101]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.090520 sec
reconnect   Jul 15 05:55:50 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2251]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.261432 sec
reconnect   Jul 15 06:04:53 user-VirtualBox ntpdate[2702]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.525658 sec
```

I confirm it is installed by default for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64Bit desktop & server editions.

**I gave it a try in VM, it shows only time it connects or reconnects (with Internet available). Not what you want (last time was connected)**

Note, syslog is a rotate log, if you want search all logs even old compressed ones, use `zgrep`

```
zgrep -ih ntpdate /var/log/syslog* | sort -bn -k2
```

Comment: This looks good, however can you confirm this is enabled by default at least on Ubuntu Desktop? I can't test it personally right now, but I'll indeed do that tomorrow

Comment: @kos,  I gave it a try. Unfortunately, I could see last  time it got connected, NOT last was connected.

Comment: @kos, i think this is not even a partial solution, I'll delete it afterward.

Comment: Don't delete it, it's useful and it's good for my scope, if I understood this will report the last time a (more or less) persistent connection has been made, so if I leave the machine connected for say 2 days it will report the date and the time of when the last connection was made, (i.e. 2 days before) right? Just the last thing, what happens when someone disconnects from the network and reconnects, say, 5 minutes later? Does the NTP check runs again? Or is there some kind of threshold after the last NTP check before a new NTP check is run?

Comment: @kos Yes, that's right (2 days old and if it was disconnected, we can't know till it is reconnected). Yes, if you disconnect and reconnect , it will try to update again. No, as far as I have tested it for 2.5 hours on VBox, also i don't see any schedule/cron hooks, Ubuntu also does not install `ntpd`/`openntpd` daemon by default. No, I couldn't find any as it runs as single command call and not as service/daemon.

Comment: So it's not installed by default? Oh man that looked promising! Are you sure? I had to reinstall 15.04 a couple of times recently and it always set the correct time. Maybe it fetched it from the BIOS instead of from the internet?

Comment: @kos, don't get confused, `ntpdate` is installed by default but not`ntpd`/`openntpd` daemon/service which comes in separate packages. To check that change you time&date to wrong one, disconnect then re-connect.

Comment: @kos, `ntpdate` could be used with `cron` to update time periodically, it will have same results as running a service (ntpd/openntpd). But you are looking for default configuration and no additional tunning, right?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Yes I was looking for something to use on a non configured machine. Ok, this works for me, I'll leave the question open anyway, maybe someone comes up with a killer answer. Thanks! It's a great step forward. Anyway mind that those logs rotate tough, maybe you want to add that to your answer.